CORS Issue with NestJS API and NextJS Frontend
I am experiencing CORS issues between my NestJS API and NextJS frontend applications.
Setup

API: Developed with NestJS, deployed on Vercel. CORS is configured in main.ts to allow requests from https://app.sanguedefarrapos.com.br. The API is accessible at https://api.sanguedefarrapos.com.br and works correctly via Postman.

Frontend: Developed with NextJS, also deployed on Vercel. The frontend communicates with the API using both server-side and client-side components.


Issue
While server-side requests to the API work fine, client-side requests result in a CORS error. Here is an example of a client-side request:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { parseCookies } from "nookies";

export function GroupSelect({ onChange, value }) {
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { "nextauth.token": token } = parseCookies();

      if (!token) {
        return;
      }

      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/groups`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(await response.json().message);
      }

      setGroups(await response.json());
    })();
  }, []);
  
  // UI rendering logic
}

However, I receive the following error when making this request from the client-side component:
Access to fetch at 'https://api.sanguedefarrapos.com.br/groups' from origin 'https://app.sanguedefarrapos.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Attempted Solutions
I have also tried enabling CORS with the default configuration in NestJS using app.enableCors(), but this did not resolve the issue either. The problem persists with client-side requests being blocked due to CORS policy.
Additional Context

API URL: https://api.sanguedefarrapos.com.br
Frontend URL: https://app.sanguedefarrapos.com.br

Given my configuration, I expected the CORS settings to allow requests from https://app.sanguedefarrapos.com.br. What might be missing or incorrectly configured in my setup?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

could you pleease share the code with CORS configuration on the API side
